# saving excel content to a database through asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic, ado

i used the code below to upload an excel file to the server. now i need to save it to a database. can anyone guide mehow to do that?

```vb
 Dim SQLStr   
 SQLStr = "INSERT ALL INTO TABLENAME "  
 for each file in filCollection  
   file_name =  file.name   
    path = folderObj & "\" & file_name  
    Set objExcel_chk = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
    Set ws1 = objExcel_chk.Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(1)  
     row_cnt = 1  


      'for row_cnt = 6 to 7  
      ' if ws1.Cells(row_cnt,col_cnt).Value <> "" then  
      '  col = col_cnt   
      ' end if  
      'next    
      While (ws1.Cells(row_cnt, 1).Value <> "")   
      for col_cnt = 1 to 10       

       SQLStr = SQLStr & "VALUES('" & ws1.Cells(row_cnt, 1).Value & "')"  
      next  
      row_cnt = row_cnt + 1  
      WEnd  


     'objExcel_chk.Quit  
     objExcel_chk.Workbooks.Close()  
     set ws1 = nothing  
     objExcel_chk.Quit  

     Response.Write(SQLStr)  

      'set filobj = FSYSObj.GetFile (sub_fol_path & "\" & file_name)  
      'filobj.Delete  

    next  
End if  
End If
```

Comment: Do you want to save the file as a binary, or save the values inside the Excel sheet?

Comment: i want to save values inside the excel file to a database

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 1):

[Read From Excel](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/classic-asp-read-excel-file-into-recordset-141448.html)

The link above says you have to have Excel installed on the server and you must have the proper permissions set on the Excel file to read from it. Outside of this process, I'm not sure how you would do it.

Comment: That looks like the way to go to me.  Read the Excel into a recordset and then use the recordset to do an insert.